# Background not displayed in it's full resolution

Tags: 14.04, desktop-background, scaling

I don't know if it is a Ubuntu scaling problem or a bug, but on my hidpi screen, my background image is like 1600x900 instead of being 3200x1800.

It doesn't affect the login screen where the background image is much sharper, at 3200x1800.

Thanks!

Comment: Which graphics drivers do you use? NVIDIA? AMD/ATI? Intel? What is your model of graphics card and the Ubuntu version you are using? Have you experienced the same problem in the past?

Comment: What is the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options`? It should be 'zoom'. Probably for some reason, it is set incorrectly. Set it by the command: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options zoom` (or from System Settings > Appearance > )

Comment: @Smile4ever It is an intel 5500. I have it since one month and it has always been like that.  And Jacob, it is unfortunalty already set as zoom.

Comment: Which background are you using?

Comment: It depends, but always a more than 3200x1800 image. And the result is always a little blurry, whereas open the same photo in a photo viewer results in a much sharper image